# SVG in parent element overlaps SVG in child element in Angular Templates

Tags: css, angular, svg

I am attempting to use an SVG in an Angular templet. However the parent element of the router outlet has an SVG as a background image. For some reason the background image is overlapping the SVG in the child element. I have included a screenshot of the DOM tree. You can see the two object elements holding the SVG's.

[image]

Next is a screenshot of the SVG in the child element when the parent SVG is not added:

[image]

After adding the SVG object in the parent element it overlaps the child SVG:

[image]

I assumed the SVG's would be rendered in the order placed into the DOM which makes sense to me. I guess I am missing something. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Can you show us a real example with code?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.landing-page-hero {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
}
```